# cordova-plugin-background-mode rejected by iOS: ' remove the "audio" setting'

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, binary, uibackgroundmode

We are using the 'cordova-plugin-background-mode' by katzer and have been approved once by the iOS revision team after I demo a video of the app using the plugin. But when we attempted to update our app last week Apple rejected us and will not accept an other "demo video".

Our Ionic App needs to run in the background and this cordova backgroud plugin seems to our only solution for this.

Apparently this plugin comes with an audio file at 0 volume that 'plays in the background in other words it's 'tricking' or mimic native functionality to keep the app running in the background. Android seems to be ok with it but Apple sends us this.

> The audio key is intended for use by apps that provide audible content
>   to the user while in the background, such as music player or streaming
>   audio apps. Please revise your app to provide audible content to the
>   user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting
>   from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Obviously we can't do that because then the core functionality of the app running in the background will not work. I guess this is what Hybrid Mobile App developers have to deal with to achieve certain native features.

[image]

Any Ionic devs out there who have figured out a work around for this?

Comment: It's not because it's hybrid, it's because Apple forbids apps to run in background, native apps too. Playing a silent sound it's a hack and Apple caught you. Here you can read more about the only background modes that apple allows, maybe one of them is suitable for what you need https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html